# Redirect to another website without changing the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an AWS beanstalk WordPress application running behind an Elastic Loadbalancer and would like the WP website to open a page from one of the S3 websites with cloudfront without the change in the URL in the address bar. For instance wpbeanstalk.com/xyz should open s3website.com/a1/page.html. I have tried doing this with RewriteRule in. Htaccess but the URL changes with 301, I have now used an Iframe to load the S3website page on the WP app however this not a viable solution. Can anyone advice for a best practice to achieve this?

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .ride/$ 
  RewriteRule (.*) awsS3.Website.com/f1/index.html [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you please show your RewriteRules.

Comment: @DusanBajic       # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .ride/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://awsS3.Website.com/f1/index.html [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: What happens if you just change `[R=301,L]` to `[P,L]`?

Comment: @DusanBajic  I was able to get the redirection working with the `[P,L]` however the S3 bucket website has a cloundfront with a SSL Cert and when I hit the desired URL the browser attempts to access the S3 website but it fails with a Cloudfront bad request . The cloudfront is set as a custom origin for with S3 website Endpoint . I wonder how do I get pass this - Please advise your thoughts on this .Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could put the CloudFront in-front of your Wordpress site and S3 bucket and then configure a Lamdba@edge function to modify the origin response with the correct S3 file.

Comment: can this be done for a website/domain instead of s3 file?